# How to calculate all the maximal ideals that contain $(X-1,Y-1,T^6+Z^6+Z^5,Z+X)$ in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y,Z,T]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field.
I need to calculate all the maximal ideals that contain $\mathfrak{a}=(X-1,Y-1,T^6+Z^6+Z^5,X+Z)=(X-1,Y-1,T^6+X^6-X^5,X+Z)=(X-1,Y-1,T^6,X+Z)$  in $\mathbb{K}[X,Y,Z,T]$.

I have tried doing the following:

Let $\mathfrak{b}$ be a maximal ideal which contains $\mathfrak{a}$. As a result, we have that $X-1,Y-1,T^6,X+Z \in \mathfrak{b}$.

Because of this, I have defined $\mathfrak{b}$ in the following way: $$\mathfrak{b}=(X-1,Y-1,T^6,X+Z,f_1(X,Y,Z,T),f_2(X,Y,Z,T),...)$$ where $f_i(X,Y,Z,T) \in  \mathbb{K}[X,Y,Z,T]$, $\forall i \geq 1$.

Apart from that, we have these congruences: $$ X \equiv 1 (mod(X-1))$$ $$ Y \equiv 1 (mod(Y-1))$$  $$ Z \equiv -X \equiv -1 (mod(X+Z))$$
So $f_i(X,Y,Z,T)\equiv f_i(1,1,-1,T)=g_i(T) \in \mathbb{K}[T]$, $ \forall i \geq 1$.
Therefore, $$\mathfrak{b}=(X-1,Y-1,T^6,Z+1,g_1(T),g_2(T),...) $$
But I don't know which polinomials I should choose so that $\mathfrak{b}$ is maximal...

I would be really thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: $\mathbb{K}$ ought to be more than a set -- probably an algebraically closed field? You should specify.

Comment: I would replace the fourth generator with $Z+1$.

Comment: Also, this is basically exactly the same as [the question you posted an hour ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3989297/19006). The solution method is also exactly the same. Was my answer there confusing to you?

Comment: In this case,  K is a field (doesn't say if it is closed). Can I use the same metod?

Comment: Assuming that $\Bbb{K}$ is at least a field you have a homomorphism of rings
$$\phi:\Bbb{K}[X,Y,T,Z]\to \Bbb{K}[T],$$
$f(X,Y,T,Z)\mapsto f(1,1,T,-1)$. The kernel of $\phi$ is generated by $X-1,Y-1,Z+X$. Hence the maximal ideals containing $\mathfrak{b}$ are the inverse images of the maximal ideals of $\Bbb{K}[T]$ containing $T^6$.

Comment: @a12456 In general, no, but you can still do this problem by solving the system of polynomial equations -- you just need to be careful and justify that these are the only maximal ideals contained in $\mathfrak{a}$.